# Significato di "da una lira l'uno"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> M’aveva comandato di salar l’acqua alle bestie e io gliel’avevo salata; lui m’uscí fuori che non s’era neanche sognato di comandarmelo e mi strapazzò ben bene. Io mi feci le mie ragioni e già che avevo preso l’abbrivo gliela intonai della paga. Si mise a far dei gridi **da una lira l’uno** e fortuna che i due figli erano via altrimenti uscivano fuori a picchiarmi come se io stessi scorticando loro padre. Mi gridò che eravamo tutti lí solo per succhiargli il sangue a lui, che non era lecito chiedergli di crescermi la paga solo perché avevo visto passar l’anno senza tempesta né brina, che adesso i merdoni di diciott’anni rompevano i patti fatti da uomini di sessanta, e finí che potevo subito farmi il fagotto e liberargli il paglione per quella sera stessa, che lui aveva già sottomano chi pigliava il mio posto a molto meno e ringraziare.

La mia domanda è: qual è il significato dell'espressione "gridi da una lira l’uno" che appare in questo testo? È chiaro che si tratta di un uso figurato,  ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 2):

Su Treccani per [lira](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lira1/) puoi trovare l'espressione ***costare due lire***:

> 2. Con valore generico, in frasi negative, quantità minima di denaro (cfr. *soldo, quattrino*): *non avere una l., non valere una lira;
>      costare due lire; comprare con poche lire*.

per dire costare poco, e riferito ad una cosa o una situazione, essere di scarso valore.

In questo caso però mi pare che il significato sia esattamente il contrario anche perché considerando che l'opera è del 1954 (e [una lira di quell'epoca risulti essere pari all'equivalente di 0,02€ attuali](http://www.infodata.ilsole24ore.com/2015/04/14/se-potessi-avere-calcola-il-potere-dacquisto-in-lire-ed-euro-con-la-macchina-del-tempo/?refresh_ce=1)) dal contesto da te citato si desume che le grida fossero quasi disumane, tanto che avrebbero scatenato una reazione violenta e sconsiderata dei due figli.

A conferma di ciò, lo stipendio dell'io narrante, che lavorava come contadino da questo Tobia Rabino (quello che grida nel brano), era di sette marenghi l’anno e credo che un marengo corrispondesse a 20 lire. Quindi, ci volevano tre giorni di lavoro per guadagnare una lira.

Comment: Penso anch'io che nei tempi di questa storia (che non sono molto ben precisati) una lira fosse una quantità importante. Per esempio, lo stipendio dell'io narrante, che lavorava come contadino da questo Tobia Rabino, era di sette marenghi l’anno e credo che un marengo corrispondesse a 20 lire. Quindi, ci volevano tre giorni di lavoro per guadagnare una lira.

Comment: Quindi la mia impressione sembra essere esatta. Aggiungerei il tuo commento alla risposta...

Comment: Quindi, sembra che qui stia a significare qualcosa di esagerato. Sarebbe interessante vedere se questa espressione o qualcosa di simile appare in qualche dizionario ottocentesco con questo significato.